# Returning a value from a TableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview

If I click on a TableViewCell I can return the cell number with:

```
indexPath.row+1
```

What I want to return is the value of one of the labels in the cell. This avoids me having to create an array in parallel and pulling the answer from that.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get a reference to a specific cell in a tableview by passing in its index path, which is known in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Once you have a reference to this cell, you can access whichever of its properties you want. Heres an example of how to get the text from each of a cell's labels.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *labelText = cell.textLabel.text;
    NSString *detailText = cell.detailTextLabel.text;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, when I do a variant of this: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
all it returns is "Label" ???
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"LocationsCell"; DatabasesTVCE *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *celltest = cell.displayDatabaseRecordNumber.text;